# Calculating determinant of matrix $n\times n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Given $$M := \mbox{diag} (1, 2, \dots, n) - n \, I_n + n \,1_n 1_n^T$$compute the determinant of $M$.

Comment: So if $n=3$ then,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 3 & 3\end{pmatrix}? $$

Comment: I believe it is $-(-1)^n n!$...

Comment: @johannesvalks well... yes it is.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Cool, I now see your post... Vote up!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** This is a rank one update of a diagonal matrix.  In particular, we have
$$
M = 
\pmatrix{
1-n\\
&2-n\\
&& \ddots\\
&&& 0 
} + 
n \cdot xx^T
$$
where $x = (1,\dots,1)^T$.
We can find the determinant of this matrix using [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem) (more specifically, using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)).

---

**Full Solution:** Let $M(t) = M + tI$. Let
$$
D(t) = 
\pmatrix{
1-n+t\\
&2-n+t\\
&& \ddots\\
&&& t 
}
$$
We note that for $t \neq 0$ (and such that $D(t)$ is invertible),
$$
\det[M(t)] = 
\det[D(t) + nxx^T] = 
\det[D(t)]\det[I + n[D(t)]^{-1}xx^T] = \\
\det[D(t)](1 + n\,x^T[D(t)]^{-1}x) = \\
\left( \prod_{k=1}^n (k-n+t)\right)
\left(1 + n \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k - n + t} \right) = \\
\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (k-n+t)\right)
\left(t\left[1 + n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k - n + t} \right]
+ n\right)
$$
We then have
$$
\det(M) = \lim_{t \to 0} \det(M(t)) = 
\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (k-n)\right)\cdot n = (-1)^{n-1}\,n!
$$

Comment: In retrospect, there's a much quicker (or equally quick) approach using Gaussian elimination.

Comment: If $$M := \underbrace{\mbox{diag} (1, 2, \dots, n)}_{=:D} - n \, I_n + n \,1_n 1_n^T$$ then $$\det(M) = \det (D - n I_n) + n 1_n^T \mbox{adj} (D_n - n I_n) 1_n = 0 + n (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)! = (-1)^{n-1} n!$$where we used the adjugate of a diagonal matrix, which is easy to compute. In this case, only the southeast corner of the adjugate is nonzero.

Comment: I didn't know about the adjugate formula, but that definitely works