# Determinant of a general Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What are the steps to solve for the Determinant of this Matrix?
I thought about turning it into a lower triangular Matrix, but I can't figure how.

Thanks in advance.

Let $A = $
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1+a2 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1& 1 + a3 &\cdots & 1 \\ \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ 1& 1 & 1 &\cdots& 1 + an \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Hint : Subtract the first row from every other row. You immediately see that $D=a_2\cdot a_3\cdots a_n$

Comment: Neither the close-vote nor the downvote are justified since in the question, the key idea is mentioned.

Comment: I love you so much. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I use an alternate (but not necessarily better) approach on a [similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1369072/81360).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determinant of rank-one perturbation of a diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730134/determinant-of-rank-one-perturbation-of-a-diagonal-matrix)